# Getting This Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './upload_images/Image_1.jpg'

Tags: python, scripting, streamlit

Please help me I am Getting This error:
[Please Check the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlB6A.png)

I am trying to upload a picture to fetch calaroies of that image. I am getting this error while uploading the image

The below is my complete code please help me

```
def run():
    st.title("Fruits-Vegetable Classification")
    img_file = st.file_uploader("Choose an Image", type=["jpg", "png"])
    if img_file is not None:
        img = Image.open(img_file).resize((250, 250))
        st.image(img, use_column_width=False)
        save_image_path = './upload_images/' + img_file.name
        with open(save_image_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(img_file.getbuffer())

        # if st.button("Predict"):
        if img_file is not None:
            result = processed_img(save_image_path)
            print(result)
            if result in vegetables:
                st.info('**Category : Vegetables**')
            else:
                st.info('**Category : Fruit**')
            st.success("**Predicted : " + result + '**')
            cal = fetch_calories(result)
            if cal:
                st.warning('**' + cal + '(100 grams)**')


run()
```

While uploading the Image I am getting error File not Found

Comment: Does the path exist?  What operating system?

Comment: The folder `upload_images` is supposed to be under your project folder. Do you have `upload_images` folder?